# Weird behavior: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, symfony-2.7

I have this Apache virtual host definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server1.qa.com
    ServerAlias server2.qa.com
    ServerAlias server3.qa.com

    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log

    LogFormat "%h %l %t \"%r\" \"%{X-PDONE-SESSION-ID}i\" %>s %b" common
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

If I call `http://server1.qa.com` without `app_dev.php` I end with this error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

If I call instead `http://server1.qa.com/app_dev.php` all is good and app works. Where is the problem? This is a Symfony 2.7 project and I'm trying to setup the `DirectoryIndex` for that path, any advice?

This is the `.htaccess` definition:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**access.log**

There are nothing weird or helpful in `access.log` as seeing in the lines below:

```
// called server1.qa.com

[04/Sep/2015:12:25:09 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 618

// called server1.qa.com/app_dev.php
[04/Sep/2015:12:25:14 -0400] "GET /app_dev.php HTTP/1.1" 302 340
[04/Sep/2015:12:25:14 -0400] "GET /app_dev.php/admin/login HTTP/1.1" 302 416
[04/Sep/2015:12:25:15 -0400] "GET /app_dev.php/login HTTP/1.1" 200 21521
[04/Sep/2015:12:25:16 -0400] "GET /app_dev.php/_wdt/c84bab HTTP/1.1" 200 40961
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution to my issue, perhaps no the best one or the easy one but recommended by [**Christian Flothmann**](https://github.com/xabbuh) here on this [comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/534#issuecomment-138102649). The Apache Virtual Host definition is as shown below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server1.com
    ServerAlias server2.com
    ServerAlias server3.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web

    # if we're setting up production environment
    # DirectoryIndex app.php

    # if we're setting up development or qa environment
    # DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

    <Directory /var/www/html/web>
        AllowOverride None #important rule, do not allow any .htaccess
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]

        # if we're setting up production environment
        # RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]

        # if we're setting up development or qa environment
        # RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log

    LogFormat "%h %l %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

> **Note:** It is important to read reviews, some rules must be applied depending on the environment that we will configure that means comments at begin of the line should be removed for properly functioning of Apache and application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will try again.

I think it will be easier to have two .htaccess files, one for every environment:

- Remove DirectoryIndex from your virtual host file
- Copy your .htaccess to .htaccess_dev
- Replace in .htaccess_dev all "app.php" to "app_dev.php"
- In your virtual host add "AccessFileName .htaccess_dev" and restart your apache.

Now, your .htaccess_dev will be used and it should not touch your app.php file.

Comment: Did you removed those lines manually? I have create a new project by running `symfony new temp_project` and the created `.htaccess` file has those two lines, I don't think that's the problem also these are the comments above those lines `# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache`

Comment: Nope, I didn't remove them manually. My project was firstly build with Symfony 2.3 and I upgraded up to 2.7, it never had these lines. If you look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/web/.htaccess , these lines aren't there.

Comment: Ummm well the new Symfony 2.7 add those by default I don't know what they are or if I can get ride of them easily, for some reason Symfony team should add them

Comment: Could you inspect access log to see what are the redirections?

Comment: I've added that info to the main post, pls take a look

Comment: Updated my question, sorry but can not start a chat, not enough reputation.

Comment: I can, tell me when you're available. I don't want to add `/app_dev.php` to the URLs and I think your solution still need this. I am not sure

Comment: No, my solution will not add app_dev.php. You could try it in your own computer, is quite safe.

Comment: I fixed a typo at last step. If this doesn't work, I don't know what is happening. You will need to discover where the redirections are happening.

Comment: Do you have redirection module enabled in apache server?

Comment: Nope, I didn't have that module enabled

Comment: Enable it with "sudo a2enmod rewrite"

Comment: Ahhh waits, you asked about redirection module and I was looking for that one but you mean `rewrite_module` which **yes** it's enabled

Answer (score 0):

You have your vhost setup so that `app_dev.php` is the index, but in your htaccess file, it uses `app.php`. Try changing to use `app_dev.php` instead:

```
# don't really need this, it's in your vhost
#DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't fix the issue either, I've tried and still the same issue